# How to edit Stories part of my webpage to make Facebook like stories effect in CSS?

Tags: css, scroll, slider, customization, custom-stories

**Current Stories are arranged in two rows:**

[image]

But, ***I would like to rearrange the STORIES part on the home page circled in red on ONE LINE but in such a way as to allow sliding (scrolling)*** from left to right and vice versa (and from right to left) a bit like stories on Facebook. As can be seen in the screenshot just below, this is the `bwg_container2_0` CSS class:

[image]

So ***how to proceed to rearrange the Stories in CSS on a SINGLE LINE instead of the current two lines and how especially to add the SLIDING effect to scroll the images from left to right ???***

Thank you please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can add following styling to bwg_container2_0 class:

```
bwg_container2_0{
    display : flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    max-height :200px;
    overflow-x: scroll;
}
```